# IE8 Crashes Strangely on JavaScript Popup

Tags: javascript, https, popup, tinymce, internet-explorer-8

I am facing a strange issue after the popup is created `onclick`. The popup opens up but hangs immediately on IE8 (works fine on all the other browsers including IE6). But on adding the `alert`box as show in the JavaScript code, the popup works fine.

> I am using `**https**` and not `**http**` and i feel popup is not able to load the JS file because of `SSL`.

Here is the how i am generating the `onclick` event:

```
<a id="forgotPasswordLink" href="#" onclick="openSupportPage();"> Some Text </a>
```

The `onclick` function is defined this way:

```
        function openSupportPage() {
            var features = "width=700,height=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes";
            var winId = window.open('', '', features);
            winId.focus();
            winId.document.open();
            winId.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/default.css" type="text/css">\n');
            var is_ie6 = (
            window.external && typeof window.XMLHttpRequest == "undefined");
            alert(is_ie6);/*The JS include below*/
                          /*works in popup only with this alert box.*/
                          /*else IE8 Hangs*/
                winId.document.write('<script src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript">Script_IE8</script>\n');


            winId.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">\n');
            winId.document.write('function inittextarea() {\n');
            winId.document.write('tinyMCE.init({  \n');
            winId.document.write('elements : "content",\n');
            winId.document.write('theme : "advanced",\n');
            winId.document.write('readonly : true,\n');
            winId.document.write('mode : "exact",\n');
            winId.document.write('theme : "advanced",\n');
            winId.document.write('readonly : true,\n');
            winId.document.write('setup : function(ed) {\n');
            winId.document.write('ed.onInit.add(function() {\n');
     winId.document.write('tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceToggleVisualAid");\n');
            winId.document.write('});\n');
            winId.document.write('}\n');
            winId.document.write('});}</script>\n');
            winId.document.write('</head><body onload="inittextarea()">\n');
            winId.document.write('  \n');
            var hiddenFrameHTML = document.getElementById("HiddenFrame").innerHTML;
            hiddenFrameHTML = hiddenFrameHTML.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&");
            hiddenFrameHTML = hiddenFrameHTML.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
            hiddenFrameHTML = hiddenFrameHTML.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
            winId.document.write(hiddenFrameHTML);
            winId.document.write('<textarea id="content" rows="10" style="width:100%">\n');
            winId.document.write(document.getElementById(top.document.forms[0].id + ":supportStuff").innerHTML);
            winId.document.write('</textArea>\n');
            var hiddenFrameHTML2 = document.getElementById("HiddenFrame2").innerHTML;
            hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&");
            hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
            hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
            winId.document.write(hiddenFrameHTML2);
            winId.document.write('</body></html>\n');
            winId.document.close();
    }
```

Please help me on this one. I could provide more information on this if needed.

> I have referred to these posts
>   already:
>
> - [Importing js file in https page using http URL in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776639/problem-of-import-js-file-in-https-page-in-ie8)
> - [Force Browser Mode=IE8 and document mode=IE8 Standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597289/force-browser-modeie8-and-document-modeie8-standards)
>
> **Additional Information**:
>
> - [Screen shot of the page](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/7190/72961203.png)
> - [Rendered HTML](http://pastebin.org/295861)
> - [Original JSPF](http://pastebin.org/296864)

Comment: why is the JavaScript in two different places? `./` current directory and `../` parent directory

Comment: when does IE crash in a way that isn't strange? of course, it may be stranger to see it work as expected...

Comment: @Nalum I am using different JS files for these browsers. But i could merge them.But i could merge them I tried with a single JS file and that didn't help

Comment: @Joseph The problem is it is working in IE6!

Comment: @Nalum Tried merging the 2 files and have updated the above code as well. But still the popup works only with alert();

Comment: What do `HiddenFrame` and `HiddenFrame2` contain? Do you have an example page, so we can step through your code?

Comment: @Marcel Here is a screenshot http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/7190/72961203.png and here is the code snippet http://pastebin.org/295861 . Hope this helps

Comment: I suspect [this code](http://pastebin.org/295861) contains the result in your new window `winId`. But what do the original `HiddenFrame` and `HiddenFrame2` contain? E.g., are they real frames, including a new `<head>` and `<body>`? Besides, why is that `Script_IE8_IE6` inside your `<script>` element? Also note that mentioned code doesn't contain a Doctype, letting IE et al. revert back to quirks mode.

Comment: @Marcel I have added the DOCTYPE and removed the `Script_IE8_IE6` within the script includes. this doesn't seem to help. Also here is the original .jspf page before the page gets rendered http://pastebin.org/296864 This doesn't seem to help

Comment: @Marcel Also, i have commented out all the lines in the code http://pastebin.org/296871 and retained only the `<script/>` include tag. This is crashing IE8, which i believe hints that it is this line that might be breaking.

Comment: Nice you deduced your issue to this. So IE 8 doesn't crash without that element? And what happens if you load an arbitrary JavaScript file (to see if the problem has something to do with (your version of) tiny_mce.js or with scripts being included in a new window this way)? And, just curious, what happens if you use HTML instead of XHTML (like `<!DOCTYPE html>`)? I don't think the latter will make any difference, but you have to try things...

Comment: @Marcel as of now I am using the latest version of TinyMCE. I have also changed the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final working function which solved my issue and works in IE6, IE7, IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

```
function openSupportPage() {
    var features="width=700,height=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes";            
    var winId=window.open('','',features);
    winId.document.open();
    winId.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title + '</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/default.css" type="text/css">\n');

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        winId.document.write(
          '<script src="../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></scr' + 'ipt>\n'
        );
    }, 10);

    winId.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">\n');
    winId.document.write('function inittextarea() {\n');
    winId.document.write('tinyMCE.init({  \n');  
    winId.document.write('elements : "content",\n');
    winId.document.write('theme : "advanced",\n');
    winId.document.write('readonly : true,\n');
    winId.document.write('mode : "exact",\n');
    winId.document.write('theme : "advanced",\n');
    winId.document.write('readonly : true,\n');
    winId.document.write('setup : function(ed) {\n');
    winId.document.write('ed.onInit.add(function() {\n');
    winId.document.write('tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand("mceToggleVisualAid");\n');
    winId.document.write('});\n');
    winId.document.write('}\n');
    winId.document.write('});}</script>\n');

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        winId.document.write('</head><body onload="inittextarea()">\n');
        winId.document.write('  \n');
        var hiddenFrameHTML = document.getElementById("HiddenFrame").innerHTML;
        hiddenFrameHTML = hiddenFrameHTML.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&");
        hiddenFrameHTML = hiddenFrameHTML.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
        hiddenFrameHTML = hiddenFrameHTML.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
        winId.document.write(hiddenFrameHTML); 
        winId.document.write('<textarea id="content" rows="10" style="width:100%">\n');
        winId.document.write(document.getElementById(top.document.forms[0].id + ":supportStuff").innerHTML);
        winId.document.write('</textArea>\n');
        var hiddenFrameHTML2 = document.getElementById("HiddenFrame2").innerHTML;
        hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&");
        hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&lt;/gi, "<");
        hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
        //hiddenFrameHTML2 = hiddenFrameHTML2.replace(/&amp;/gi, "&").replace(/&lt;/gi, "<").replace(/&gt;/gi, ">");
        winId.document.write(hiddenFrameHTML2); 
        winId.document.write('</body></html>\n');
        winId.document.close();
    }, 300);
}
```

I got a lot of help from these questions:

- [Formatting this JavaScript Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949234/formatting-this-javascript-line)
- [JavaScript source file not loading in IE8 Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950405/javascript-source-file-not-loading-in-ie8-popup)

Thank you all.