# https on ie: popup windows don't work properly (because of scripts)

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, https, popupwindow

I've a jquery ajax call:

```
var popup = function () {
  if (myurl) {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myurl,
    data: mydata,
    success: function (response) {  

        // other code here                  
        var x=window.open('', '_blank', 'titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height='+height+',width='+width+',resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,location=0,status=no,left='+left+',top='+top+'');
        x.document.open();
        x.focus();
        x.document.writeln(response);
        x.document.close();

        return false;
    },

    error: function () {  
        return false;
    },
  });
 }
};
```

It worked on all browser (on http), but since I use https, the popup window opens and loops without displaying anything and blocks the browser on IE (I tested on ie 8, 9 and 10). On Chrome and Firefox it continues to work.

**EDIT**

The response which I write on the popup contains jquery/javascript script which cause the issue.
But how could I prevent this?

**EDIT2**

In the jsp (used to create the popup content) I've put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
javascript code
// -->
</script>
```

This resolves in part the issue.

What for the imported js file?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

the path to the jquery file is relative, but the issue still remains.
Also if I use external links with https.

If I import js file by using

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

all "works" fine, that is IE browser doesn't block when the popup is opened, but I would a solution that allows the script execution

**EDIT3**

The issue was caused by the ie compatibility mode IE=8
I removed it from the popup page and its parent page and I resolved on IE 10, but what for IE 8 and 9? (without scripts the popup is well displayed on IE)

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943965/ie8-crashes-strangely-on-javascript-popup

Comment: @RobM.: It's not an issue with import of js files, cause I've all relative paths

Comment: Why are you doing this with ajax?

Comment: @turboHz: I'm using a jquery plugin to build form with json. The popup shows the form preview to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

f you have add any resource which use another protocol - that would cause an error in IE 8-9.

So you should check if javascript in your new window makes request to https, and all content has https, including images, etc.

Comment: I tried by importing only one extern script i.e. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`, but also in this way it fails (note `https`)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be from extra commma `,` after error function.

In ajax call, **last parameter/attibute to `$.ajax` call must not be follwed by commma `,`**.

This works well with all new browsers, but **old browsers like IE 7 throws js error on that line & subsequent requests stops**.

```
var popup = function () {
  if (myurl) {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myurl,
    data: mydata,
    success: function (response) {  

        // other code here                  
        var x=window.open('', '_blank', 'titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height='+height+',width='+width+',resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,location=0,status=no,left='+left+',top='+top+'');
        x.document.open();
        x.focus();
        x.document.writeln(response);
        x.document.close();

        return false;
    },

    error: function () {  
        return false;
    }//,   <= Remove this extra comma
  });
 }
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Removing the comma doesn't resolve the issue (I tried it on IE9)

Comment: Make sure script is not cached try deleting browsing history & refresh using ctrl+f5